# PHP Live Server/Live Server Extension for Google Chrome Using VS Code Editor

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

In an effort to get PHP running on a live server like that which has been done for HTML/CSS/JavaScript, I looked at some guides for it.

I have:

1. VS Code
2. XAMPP
3. VS Code plugin 'Live Server'
4. and the Google Chrome extension: 'Live Server Extension'.

However, nothing is working. Doesn't matter if I turn the live server extension on in my Chrome window or input my server address and live server address, nothing works.
There are no great videos on this, or maybe the ones I've seen are good but I'm just missing a step.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried this : https://github.com/ritwickdey/live-server-web-extension

Comment: Yes, I've searched high and low, that website and many not-so-great tutorials. It's seems like either it's not a common problem or nobody knows how to fix it.